# Selecting multiple axes from a pandas dataframe, what is the best approach?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have created a pandas dataframe that looks like this:-

[image: DataFrame]

Now let's assume that I want to query the dataframe to grab the costs of the items purchased from 'Store 1'. Which method is most appropriate (faster and less prone to errors):

1. `df.loc['Store 1', 'Cost']`
2. `df.T.loc['Cost']`
3. `df.loc['Store 1']['Cost']`
4. `df.loc[:,['Name', 'Cost']]`

Comment: `df.loc['Store 1', 'Cost']` I would use this over all the other options.

Comment: first off, no 4. will return all the rows, which is not what you want(You want only Store 1 and cost). no.1 will give you the costs for store 1, but it wont be associated with an item. no. 2 doesn't quite make sense to me, as u will not be getting for just store 1. option 3 is frowned upon; you should have your rows and columns identifiers within the ```loc``` brackets. the closest is option 1, but it will just return only the costs.

Answer (score 1):

I think first is best for selecting by index and columns labels.

Second method with transpose select `Cost` column, in my opinion overcomplicated way, because same output like `df['Cost']`.

Third is not recommended, because if is used for setting values then possible [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters).

In fourth method are selected all rows (all index) by `:` and labels by list, not only `Store 1`.